# I have accidently deleted the file name_app.app(executable) in my Xcode project's!

Tags: objective-c, xcode, executable

I have accidently deleted the file name_app.app in my Xcode project's. How can I regenerates it? thanks

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question on exactly the same topic? Also, have you tried to simply re-build the project? What happens? What error messages are displayed?

Comment: `YourSCM revert YourProject.xcodeproj`? SCNR

Comment: Because my previous question was for the xcode 4 preview 6... the file .app is written in red and I can't find the path of the file for subitting it to the apple store!

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference which version of Xcode. What happens when you try and re-build the app? (**If you can't provide more detail, we can't provide any help, as you're not telling us anything useful.**)

Comment: When I build the project it runs fine on device and simulator... but when I try to show the file with .app exstension in Finder... I'm not able to find it... infact in the project is written in red... like a file that is not included in the project... I don't understand why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're attempting to prepare your application for submission to the App Store, you really need to read the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) as this explains in detail how to prepare your application for submission.

(N.B.: You *might* need to log-in to the Apple developer portal for the above link to work.)